# Loading a Windows From a user control in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

i have  a window(mainwindows) and i am using dockpanel inside that and loading usercontrol inside that dockpanel. this usercontrol(Newplan usercontrol) is having a stack of the button and a contentcontrol inside and two button Next and Cancel.

what i need to do is that when i am pressing the next button it is loading usercontrol of next step (with is according to the button in stack panel) so when when user is in last step (which is finish and inside the newplan usercontrol's contentcontrol and finish button in inside the newplan usercontrol. so when finsih button will pressed main starting window(mainwindow) should come.

how can i do this.

this is my first post. Sorry for poor english and description.

Comment: An CP article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31837/Creating-an-Internationalized-Wizard-in-WPF